# How to create Validation utility for variable validation in spring boot or java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have some variable, for them validation rule may change in run time(getting validation rules from Datbase) like

String name ;
Rules: - `{Max:10, Min:3, SpacialSymbol:false, AlphaNumeric:ture,...etc}`

String age;
Rules: - `{max:100,min:19,numeric:true,alphaNumeric:false}`

So according to the variable rules may change during runtime...

I want `ValidationUtl.isValid(Object variableValue,Object rules)`

In Validation utility

```
static boolean isValid(){//rule implementation}
```

How can I do it ? in a generic way for validating all rules. I do not want to use if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare an interface

```java
interface Rule<T> {
    boolean isValid(T obj);
}
```

and then you can encapsulate various checks inside `Rule` implementations

```java
class MinLength implements Rule<String> {

    private final int min;

    MinLength(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String obj) {
        return obj.length() >= min;
    }
}

class IsAlphaNumeric implements Rule<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String obj) {
        return true; //TODO: implement the alpha-numeric check
    }
}

// other rules
```

The last thing you will need is to dynamically obtain rules from your Database and link them with `Rule` implementations.

```java
public class StringValidator {

    public boolean validate(String string, List<Rule<String>> rules) {
        boolean isValid = true;
        for (Rule<String> rule : rules) {
            if (rule.isValid(string)) {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Rule<String>> rules = Arrays.asList(new MinLength(10), new IsAlphaNumeric()); //obtain from Database
        boolean isValid = new StringValidator().validate("blablabla", rules);
    }
}
```

Comment: For creating List of Rules 
Arrays.asList(new MinLength(10), new IsAlphaNumeric());

In this list for creating object of new MinLength(10) . I will have to put if else because some variable might have this rule or might not. Is there any way to generate these object of rule implemented class dynamically from this string 
{Max:10, Min:3, SpacialSymbol:false, AlphaNumeric:ture,...etc}

This string i am getting from database

Comment: Yes, of course. You need to parse JSON (probably with Jackson), and implement sort of Rule Factory to relate `Rule` implementations with JSON attributes and their values